# WSL Nano scrolling up to see terminal

Tags: command-line, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nano

I run some commands on remote server (am connected with it via ssh using WSL ubuntu 20) and after running then I open nano editor, usually I was able to scroll up with my mouse witch allowed me to see my terminal without closing nano, I was able to copy the output of previously run commands. After setting up WSL on my new laptop I am trying to do it on the same exact remote server, but scrolling up doesn't show me my latest commands, it shows me lets say my commands without ~10 latest commands. I have to copy some parts of the output of the last command run before entering nano. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

*Short summary:*

- I can reproduce your *desired behavior* in Ubuntu/WSL using Windows Terminal
- I can reproduce the behavior that you *don't like* in Ubuntu/WSL using the legacy Windows Console Host

*More Detail:*

The `nano` editor, and most other terminal-based editors, typically run in what is known as an [alternate screen buffer](https://terminalguide.namepad.de/mode/p47/).  The *usual* (some would say "correct") behavior for a terminal when in this mode, as @pa4080 mentions in [another answer that appeared while I was typing this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1400437/1165986) is *not* to allow scrolling above the alternate buffer.  Some terminals will send up/down keys in response to a scroll up/down while in this mode.

Oddly, this is an issue ([Github issue link](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/3321)) in the *new* Windows Terminal, which you may have installed on your previous machine.  The behavior does *not* occur in the (much) older Windows Console host, the *default* terminal on Windows 10 and (currently) Windows 11.

It sounds to me like you may be using the older console now, which is behaving *correctly*, but not as you want.

My recommendation is:

- Install and switch to Windows Terminal
- But don't rely on that behavior, since it will likely be fixed at some point.  @pa4080 mentions one possibility of using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to send the foreground app to the background, but I'd also point you to Tmux as an alternative, which will allow you to switch between *multiple* terminal windows inside of one Windows Terminal tab.

It's also possible that you *are* using Windows Terminal, and that behavior has already been fixed in a new release without marking the issue closed (and I might be running an older Terminal without the fix).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution. I am using Windows Terminal (I forgot to mention that in the question) and I suspect this is the newest version since I downloaded it two days ago directly from Windows Store. I'll try to get used to using the "proper" way with Ctrl+Z and fg.

Answer (score 2):

According to my experience, the explained behavior - *scroll-up within `nano` to see the terminal* - is observed only in WSL. In my opinion it looks like a bug rather than a feature, but maybe I'm wrong. **Note:** to achieve it - the history in the terminal should be long enough to scroll it without `nano`.

The proper way to do what you want is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> while `nano` (or some other application) is open. This will push it to the background and you will be able to operate in the terminal (list directories or history, copy text, , etc.). When you finish just type the command `fg` to bring `nano` to the foreground again.

Comment: The "seeing the teminal" by scrolling up is available also using just putty on windows  so I am not sure if it is a bug. Thanks a lot for sharing the proper way of doing it, even though it is not as smooth as using the "trick".